# Java Compiler Batch Script

Tags: java, batch-file

I'm very new to Java. I learned to compile with the command line. But that was too slow. So I wrote a batch script, which starts at my code directory, asks for a subfolder name, asks for a file name, javac's it, and java's the resulting class file.

Feel free to stop me right here. Is Notepad++ a good choice? Should I be using an IDE? I've turned off code autofill so I can learn the syntax. If you were to go back to the basics what program do you wish you started with?

Anyway, my batch script isn't automatic enough for me. I want to be able to save presets in some sort of config file and refer back to them rather than type in my subfolder and my java file name every time I want to compile. That's my question. How do I read from a file and reference it in .bat?

Here's my batch script, its partially ripped off from some other forum:

```
@echo compiling from the java folder. If you want to specify a subfolder go ahead
@echo off
set /p UserInputPath=Subfolder?
cd C:\Users\bruh\Documents\code\java\%UserInputPath%
set /p fileName=What File would you like?
javac %fileName%.java
@echo compiled.
PAUSE
java %fileName%
PAUSE
```

Comment: Hi, your question must be more specific to be a good fit for the stackoverflow Q/A format. See [mcve] for more information

Comment: Hint: `javac *.java` - Better Hint: Ant, Maven, SBT, Gradle. And yes, use an IDE.

Comment: [Eclipse](https://eclipse.org), [Netbeans](https://netbeans.org) and IntelliJ are all excellent IDEs - far superior to BlueJ.  My personal preference is Eclipse, simply because it's most applicable to most of the Java-related projects I work on.  Another choice worth considering is [MS Visual Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/java).  It is *NOT* as strong as a Java IDE.  But it "supports" Java ... and it excels at things like Angular (front end/Javascript projects).  MS Visual Code is freely available for all of Windows, MacOS and Linux.

Answer (score 0):

> Is Notepad++ a good choice?

Probably no.  (Some Windows text editors have the nasty habit of "formatting" your code; e.g. inserting pretty quotes when you just want a straight single-quote.  I don't know if Notepad++ is guilty of doing that ...)

> Should I be using an IDE

Probably yes; see the comments and other answers for some suggestions.

But more importantly you should be using a Java build tool such as Maven, Gradle or Ant to build (and maybe run) your code.  A good IDE will have support for one or more of these, either builtin or as a plugin.  But you can also run these build tools from the command line.

While a hand-written script will work for small examples, they are unwieldy for projects involving more than a handful, of source files, external dependencies and so on.

The issue of application config settings is orthogonal to the above.  If your application's settings are too complicated (or too tedious) to be entered as command line arguments, then your *application* should implement some mechanism for reading settings from config file or similar.  There are lots of options for doing this.

> How do I read from a file ...

Java code.

> ... and reference it in .bat?

Well you could make the config file name a command line parameter for your application and pass it on the `java ...` command line.  Or you could hard-wire a default filename or pathname for the config file into your application.  Or a combination of the two.  But it is ultimately just Java code.